# Recursion in Macro Preprocessor

Tags: c, recursion, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I am trying to write a function that calculates Factorial **RECURSIVELY** but I have problem with compiling the code. BTW, I do not know if the code itself is coorect!
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FACTORIAL(n) \
    FACTORIAL_##n()

#define FACTORIAL_0() 0

#define FACTORIAL_1() 1

#define FACTORIAl_N(n) \
    FACTORIAL(n - 1) + FACTORIAL(n - 2)

#define FACTORIAL_RESULT(n) \
    FACTORIAL(n)

int main() {
    int f2 = FACTORIAL_RESULT(2);
    printf("%d\n", f2);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a bunch of errors when compiling this code such as:

```
*  Executing task: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe c.c -o d:\C\output\c.exe -Wall -Wextra -g3 

 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe c.c -o d:\C\output\c.exe -Wall -Wextra -g3 

c.c: In function 'main':
c.c:4:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FACTORIAL_2'; did you mean 'FACTORIAL_0'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    4 |     FACTORIAL_##n()
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
c.c:14:5: note: in expansion of macro 'FACTORIAL'
   14 |     FACTORIAL(n)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
c.c:17:14: note: in expansion of macro 'FACTORIAL_RESULT'
   17 |     int f2 = FACTORIAL_RESULT(2);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccuGFhBc.o: in function `main':
D:\C/c.c:17: undefined reference to `FACTORIAL_2'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

 *  The terminal process "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe 'c.c', '-o', 'd:\C\output\c.exe', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-g3'" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Anyone who can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: a) Any reason you do it with the preprocessor instead of a proper function? b) Your formula is for Fibonacci, not a factorial.

Comment: And recursion is just about the worst way possible to compute Fibonacci numbers.  (Unless it's as part of a demonstration of the power of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).)

Comment: I am learning about Macros so I am rewriting a proper function that calculates factorial into Macros. I do not know how to do it so it maybe is completely wrong!

Comment: Function-like macros are basically obsolete.  Is this an assignment someone gave you, or one you gave yourself?  To the extent that function-like macros have any use at all, it's to do things that ordinary functions can't.  So trying to rewrite an ordinary function as a macro seems a strange exercise.  If you really want to write some useful function-like macros, I'd try something like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, or `getchar()`.  (But you can't write an interesting `getchar` macro unless you're implementing all the rest of `<stdio.h>` at the same time, so never mind that suggestion.)

Comment: `#define FACTORIAl_N(n)` should be `#define FACTORIAL_N(n)`

Comment: @Glory *I am learning about Macros so I am rewriting a proper function that calculates factorial into Macros*. That is not what you should use macros for, that's like using your shoes to hammer a nail, it's simply not the tool for the job. That's what functions are for.

Comment: Macros do string (more precisely token) replacement in your source code. They do not know anything about C

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not specify any dynamic creation of macros. `#define FACTORIAL_N(n) …` will only define a single macro with a literal `N` in its name; it will not define a family of macros with different numerals in place of `N`.

Macros are not intended for looping or arbitrary recursion or nesting.